# inconsistency in numeric values after it's conversion from the character type

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion, numeric

A field `lowest_specification` in the `site data frame` is of `character` type. I have converted this field from the `character` data type to `numeric` using `as.numeric()` and stored it's values in the `numeric_lowest_specification`. This conversion happens smoothly.

However, there is inconsistency between the values of the `numeric_lowest_specification`, when I print the complete data frame than the individual field  `numeric_lowest_specification`.

**When I print complete data frame output:**

```
##    lowest_specification    numeric_lowest_specification
##        <chr>                 <dbl> 
## 1      475.0                   475 
## 2      475.0                   475 
## 3      475.0                   475 
## 4      475.0                   475 
## 5      475.0                   475 
## 6      475.0                   475 
## 7      475.0                   475 
## 8      475.0                   475 
## 9      475.0                   475 
## 10     475.0                   475
```

**When I print individual field from the data frame:**

```
    numeric_lowest_specification
##        <dbl> 
## 1      475.0 
## 2      475.0 
## 3      475.0 
## 4      475.0 
## 5      475.0 
## 6      475.0 
## 7      475.0 
## 8      475.0 
## 9      475.0 
## 10     475.0
```

So, in case of printing the individual field from the data frame the `trailing 0` is getting appended to the numbers.

I am trying to understand the possible reason behind this inconsistency.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce it. Can you share a reproducible example ?

Comment: Probably, as you are working with a `data.frame`, when you select a column, your output is printed in its format, whereas when you show the whole data, you get the information in a short way.

Comment: The internal representation of data and how it is printed are two different things.

Comment: @RonakShah Above given example is from the actual data frame. Please let me know what exact details you are expecting?